# VS 2022 - Maui - iOS Debugging Issue

Tags: maui, maui-ios

I am trying to debug my Maui app on my iOS (Android works perfectly) and I'm getting this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Automatic Provisioning is enabled but no Development Team was selected. Please select a team or switch to Manual Provisioning from the iOS Bundle Signing page.         0
```

I have already:

1. Generated an App Store API Key, downloaded the private key, and set up the Apple Developer Account in VS 2022
2. Pair to Mac: I also have paired to my local Mac which I used to have to use XCode to build my Ionic Cordova app, this is my first Maui mobile app
3. Automatic Provisioning: I have completed "Configure Automatic Provisioning" and set the Development "Team"

Anyone have any experience w/this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a discussion that has the same error message as yours](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/3972) on the github. You can try the workaround in it:

Put the following entries into the first PropertyGroup:

```
<CodesignKey>Apple Development: YOUR NAME</CodesignKey>
<CodesignProvision>VS: com.COMPANY.APPID Development</CodesignProvision>
<ProvisioningType>manual</ProvisioningType>
```

Comment: Zhang - thanks, I'll take a look! :-D

Comment: All right, hope it can help you. @RobertGreenMBA